# Second query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

First query works fine but the second query doesn't update the database. I can't find the error.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $editdes = $_GET['id'];
    $con     = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "Destinos");
    $con1    = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "var");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE Destinos SET Precio=730 WHERE Destino='$editdes'");
    mysqli_query($con1, "UPDATE var SET variable='$editdes' WHERE variable= * ");


    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: variable= '*' try to put single quotes on *

Comment: And this is why you should be checking the result from `mysqli_query`.  The error message for the failed query would have told you that `variable = *` is invalid syntax.

Comment: Please format your code!

Comment: Are you sure the 1st query works? I don't think so

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: What is `variable= *` supposed to mean? Also you should prepare, and if possible use one database.

Comment: @JohnRobertson: It should succeed, at least, assuming `Destinos` is a table.  Whether it does what was intended, though, depends on the types of `Precio` and `Destino`.

Comment: i've just removed the `WHERE variable = '*'` and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

`*` is a string if used as value of a field and should be quoted

```
UPDATE var SET variable='$editdes' WHERE variable= '*'
```

Very Important: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?lq=1)